# How to avoid having duplicate code for fetching location and data in every activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, code-duplication

I have 2 activites (one with listview and 1 with mapview). Both activities have refresh button that fetches location and then downloads some data from the internet.
I have duplicate code for location and data fetch in both activities.

How to have this code just in 1 place and to be able to call it from any activity? Can i put it in Application object?

Comment: put them in a static function. And if required, let this function take as an input an Activity instance.

Comment: There is lots of code, but it is standard: locationlistener and async task for downloading data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for example GPSGetter which keeps getting the coordinates from the GPS, Then instantiate via createInstance() method of that class, in the onCreate method of your main activity. Then define a getInstance() method in that class.

For example

```
class GPSGetter {

GPSGetter obj;


//constructor
private GPSGetter(){

//do some stuff here 
}

public GPSGetter createInstance(){
if(obj == null)
obj = new GPSGetter();
}

public getGPSGetter(){

return obj;

}
```

In this manner you can call getInstance from both of your Activity classes and do not need to worry about duplication, also this will make sure only one object of class is created.

Comment: Ok, and how to inform activity that location has been received (and data downloaded)? Should this GpsGetter call some static methods in activity? Any other mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.;


    import android.content.Context;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Looper;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.util.Log;


    /**
     * This class has the missionto get the current location, save it and manage it.
     * 
     * @author Aracem
     *
     */
    public class GetCurrentLocation implements Runnable {

    private Context mContext;
    private static GetCurrentLocation gcl = null;
    public static Location currentLocation = null;  
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;
    private MyLocationListener mLocationListener;
    private static Thread thread;
    private Handler handler = null;
    private static Location location = null;




    public static Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }


    /**
     * @param Context de la aplicacion
     * 
     * Metodo que se encarga de crear la instancia de la clase de geolocalizacion
     */
    private synchronized static void createInstance(Context c) {
        if (gcl == null) gcl = new GetCurrentLocation(c);
    }//end method


    /**
     * @param Context de la aplicacion
     * @param han Handler with the handler that we want to call when the location
     * will found.
     * 
     * Metodo que se encarga de crear la instancia de la clase de geolocalizacion
     */
    private synchronized static void createInstance(Context c, Handler han) {
        if (gcl == null) gcl = new GetCurrentLocation(c, han);
    }//end method


    /**
     * @param Context context de la aplicacion
     */
    public static GetCurrentLocation getInstance(Context c) {
        if (gcl == null) createInstance(c);

        //if (currentLocation == null) getCurrentLocation();

        return gcl;
    }//end methodd

    /**
     * @param Context context de la aplicacion
     * @param han Handler with the handler that we want to call when the location
     * will found.
     */
    public static GetCurrentLocation getInstance(Context c, Handler han) {
        if (gcl == null) createInstance(c,han);

        //if (currentLocation == null) getCurrentLocation();

        return gcl;
    }//end methodd


    protected GetCurrentLocation(Context c){
        mContext = c;
        thread = new Thread(this,"Get Location");
        thread.start();

    }

    protected GetCurrentLocation(Context c, Handler han){
        mContext = c;
        handler = han;

        thread = new Thread(this,"Get Location");
        thread.start();

    }

    /**
     * Use this method to put a handler for the listener
     * this handler is activated when location is found.
     * @param han handle that you want to activate
     * when location is found.
     */
    public synchronized void setHandler(Handler han){
        handler = han;
    }

    //Location

    public static void setCurrentLocation(Location loc) {
        currentLocation = loc;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try{

            mLocationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Looper.prepare();
                Log.i("DEBUG","Location obtain with GPS.");
                mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
                Looper.loop(); 
                Looper.myLooper().quit();  

            } else if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                Looper.prepare();
                Log.i("DEBUG","Location obtain with network.");
                mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
                Looper.loop();
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }else{
                Looper.prepare();;
                if (handler != null) handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                Log.i("DEBUG","Location cant be find.");
                Looper.loop();
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }   
        }
        catch(SecurityException e)
        {
            Log.i("DEBUG", e.getMessage() + " Continue with network_provider");

            if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
                Looper.prepare();
                Log.i("DEBUG","Location obtain with network.");
                mLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
                Looper.loop();
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }else{
                Looper.prepare();;
                if (handler != null) handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                Log.i("DEBUG","Location cant be find.");
                Looper.loop();
                Looper.myLooper().quit();
            }   
        }
    }


    /**
     * @author marcos
     * 
     * Clase de apoyo que extiende de LocationListener
     * que se utiliza para gestionar los cambios
     * en la recepción GPS tales como una nueva localizacion
     * o un cambio de Status
     */
    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {
                setCurrentLocation(loc);
                //           handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                Log.i("DEBUG","Location: " + loc.toString());

                //Stop looking for locations
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);

                //If handler isnt null, call it 
                if (handler != null){
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    msg.obj = loc;
                    if (handler != null)
                        handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    location = loc;
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                Bundle extras) {
        }
    }  

}
```